# SharePoint 2010 MySite designs inspiration - Design samples needed

Tags: 2010, branding

I needs some inspirational designs to brand the Mysites in my organization. Any inspirational designs would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the design of the fourth on this page : [SharePoint branding](http://www.sharepointedutech.com/2011/11/08/sharepoint-branding-to-brand-or-not-to-brand-now-that-is-a-question/)
You could find a lot of examples using Google.

Good Luck